# Azure Media Services Live Streaming Preview Error

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to use preview url to preview my stream before go live, but always get an error "No compatible source was found for this media". When I start the event, I have no problem playing the actual streaming url, it plays perfectly in the Azure Media player.

And another question, I see a couple video tutorials and see that preview can be used in pass through channels, but I found this in the documentation: ["When Live Encoding is enabled, you can now get a preview of the live feed as it reaches the Channel."](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/an-introduction-to-live-encoding-with-azure-media-services/), this means that only Standard channels can be used to see a preview? By the way, I tested in both channels, pass through and standard and get the same error in preview.

Update:

I'm using Chrome and just for curiosity, I open Azure Media Player in Internet Explorer and finally I can see the live feed in preview. So, what's the problem with Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable Flash in Chrome to be able to playback preview URLs from AMS because the previews are only available in the smooth streaming format. Smooth Streaming needs plugins like Flash or Silverlight to playback.

You can enable flash in a couple different ways but most commonly you can just go to content settings and enable it for whatever websites you're using.

Comment: Thank you @sraje, enable flash solves the problem in Chrome